# ResourceFunction["ConicProperties"]

Tags: resourcefunction

This seems to evaluate forever.

```
$Version
ResourceFunction["ConicProperties"][3 x^2+5 y^2-7 x y+2 x-9 y+2==0,{x,y}]
```

(* 13.0.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (January 28, 2022) *)

Do you experience the same behavior?

Also this evaluates forever:

```
ResourceFunction["ConicProperties"][3 x^2+5 y^2-7 x y+2 x-9 y+2==0,{x,y},"Type"]
```

In this code I only want to know the type of conic, which should not be computationally intensive.

Comment: I see a lot of `$Aborted` in "13.3.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" though `"Type" -> "Ellipse"` is correct. Looks like a bug.

Comment: Your second code produces `{{<|"Type" -> "Ellipse"|>}, {\[Placeholder]}}` for me.

Comment: Running almost 10 minute，`ResourceFunctionHelpers\`ConicProperties[
 3 x^2 + 5 y^2 - 7 x y + 2 x - 9 y + 2 == 0, {x, y}]`  we get `<|"Type" -> "Ellipse", 
 "Equation" -> 2 + 2 x + 3 x^2 - 9 y - 7 x y + 5 y^2 == 0, 
 "Foci" -> {{1/11 (43 - Sqrt[230 (2 + Sqrt[53])]), 
    1/11 (40 - Sqrt[230 (-2 + Sqrt[53])])}, {1/
     11 (43 + Sqrt[230 (2 + Sqrt[53])]), 
    1/11 (40 + Sqrt[230 (-2 + Sqrt[53])])}}, 
 "Vertices" -> {{1/11 (43 - Sqrt[1150 + 7935/Sqrt[53]]), ... ...`

Comment: hmmm... you really was that patient.